# In how many ways can we distribute 80 persons in a 5 wagon train?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can we distribute 80 persons in a 5 wagon train such that :

a) exactly 15 go into the first wagon

b) exactly 15 go into one of the 5 wagons

In the first case i got $\binom{68}{3}$, and 
for b)
$4^{65}.$$\binom{80}{15}$.
I wonder if my solution is correct.

Comment: Are the wagons distinct?  Are the people distinct?  Does order within a wagon matter?

Comment: For (b), "exactly 15 go into one of the 5 wagons", do you mean that exactly one of the wagons will get exactly 15 people and no other wagon gets exactly 15 people?  Do you mean at least one of the wagons will get exactly 15 people, possibly letting other wagons also get exactly 15 people?  Do you mean for a specific wagon to get exactly 15 people?  If so to that last one, how does this differ from problem (a)?

Comment: The wagons are distinct, the people are not. I don't think the order matters. That's all I've got from the teacher.

Comment: In that case, your answer to (a) is correct.  Your answer to (b) is not.  You have treated people as being distinct in your attempt for (b) and you have also neglected to consider *which* of the wagons it was that got the 15 people and have also neglected to take into account the possibility of multiple wagons each having exactly 15 people and should have used some sort of inclusion-exclusion argument.

Comment: Would youd tell me, please, how would that be with inclusion-exclusion? I tried, but I just got confused.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming wagons are distinct, people are identical (*which is a rather uncommon assumption for the record*), and we are interested in counting the number of ways in which we may distribute our 80 identical people among five distinct wagons such that there is *at least one* wagon which has exactly 15 people...

Let the number of people in each wagon be labeled as $a,b,c,d,e$ respectively.

Let $A,B,C,D,E$ be the sets of arrangements of our people among the wagons such that there are exactly 15 people in the first, second, third, fourth, and fifth wagons respectively.

We are tasked with calculating $|A\cup B\cup C\cup D\cup E|$

By inclusion-exclusion, we know this expands as $|A|+|B|+\dots+|E|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-\dots - |D\cap E|+|A\cap B\cap C|+\dots - |A\cap B\cap C\cap D|-\dots + |A\cap B\cap C\cap D\cap E|$

By symmetry, this simplifies as $\binom{5}{1}|A|-\binom{5}{2}|A\cap B|+\binom{5}{3}|A\cap B\cap C|-\binom{5}{4}|A\cap B\cap C\cap D|+\binom{5}{5}|A\cap B\cap C\cap D\cap E|$

Now... calculating $|A|$ is done exactly like how you did part (a).

Calculating $|A\cap B|$ is done almost exactly like how you did part (a), but rather than just the first wagon having 15 people, so too must the second wagon.  We have here trying to count how many nonnegative integral solutions there are to the system $\begin{cases}c+d+e=(80-15-15)\\c\geq 0\\ d\geq 0\\ e\geq 0\end{cases}$ which will be $\binom{50+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{52}{2}$

Continuing along, we can calculate the rest and come to a final answer:

> $5\binom{68}{3}-10\binom{52}{2}+10\binom{36}{1}-5\binom{20}{0}+0$